# React router the page won't stop reloading

Tags: reactjs, react-router

building simple react website for practice and trying to add routes so my menu will work. 
I tried a few ways and looked a lot in stackoverflow didn't find working solution for my problem. 
I'm not sure where to place the *Router* should i put it where my navbar located or in the index where i render the *App*?. No matter what i tried it's just getting stuck in reloading mode.

This is my latest try: i try to replace the bootstrap menu links with Link>  as it looks here:
[Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)
still the same result stuck on reloading
**The Header code where the menu code is:**

```
 function Header(props) {
  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
          <div class="mx-auto order-0">
            <a
              className="brand-stype"
              className="navbar-brand mx-auto"
              href="/"
            >
              home
            </a>
            <button
              class="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target=".dual-collapse2"
            >
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">


              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/">
                <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/about">
                  about
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

**My App.js code**

```
    const App = () => {
  return (

    <div>
      <div className="all-containers">     
         <Header />
        <Photos />
      </div>

      <HowItWorks />
      <Calc />
      <Insta />
      <Footer />

          <Switch>
           <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
           <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
           <Route render={function () {
                 return <p>Not found</p>
           }} />
          </Switch>

    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**My index.js file**

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
);
```

The error i got after adding Router as said in the comment below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your router and the top lvl:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
  <App />
</Router>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

It just injects necessary things using context so you can freely use router anywhere in your application.

Comment: Now i got an error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" any idea how i can solve it?

Comment: can you post the snippet that has that error? I don't see where you are using that?

Comment: also you have a big no-no, you have a render recursion: app is rendering header and then header is rendering app again if specific path. you should extract the switch from the header part to the app component

Comment: and remove           <Route path="/">
            <App />
          </Route>, and put here content that should be displayed on "/", your app content is the top lvl component (more like a layout component)

Comment: Updated the post and the code as you said. Deleted all except for 1 menu item for testing . Still same error

Comment: so i added     <Router history={history}>  it solved the error but when pressing on "about" it shows the full home page and in the bottom shows the about page. Any idea how can i fix it?

Comment: Fix it , added Home page and made the App.js just for routes. Thank you very much for your help!!